# How to edit Tabulator dates in the cell?

Tags: tabulator

http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1

The Editable Data example above shows the use of a custom editor for the date field (example in the link is DOB). Similar examples exist in earlier tabulator versions as well as here and Github. The javascript date picker that results works perfectly for most users but not all (even if also on Chrome). So the alternate approach often attempted by the users is to try and enter the date directly into the cell. But unfortunately this is problematic --in the same way it is with the linked example. Changing the month and day isn't too bad -- but directly changing the year is very difficult.  Does anyone have a potential solution? I've explored everything from blur/focus/different formats/"flatpicker"/etc - but I'm coming up empty.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to get full cross browser support would be to create a custom formatter that used a 3rd party datepicker library, for example the [jQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). The correct choice of date picker would depend on your needs and your existing frontend framework.

in the case of the jQuery datepicker the custom formatter could look something like this (this example uses the standard input editor, you will notice in the ***onRendered*** function it turns the standard input into the jQuery datepicker):

```
var dateEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
    var cellValue = cell.getValue(),
    input = document.createElement("input");

    input.setAttribute("type", "text");

    input.style.padding = "4px";
    input.style.width = "100%";
    input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    input.value = typeof cellValue !== "undefined" ? cellValue : "";

    onRendered(function(){
        input.style.height = "100%";
        $(input).datepicker(); //turn input into datepicker
        input.focus();
    });

    function onChange(e){
        if(((cellValue === null || typeof cellValue === "undefined") && input.value !== "") || input.value != cellValue){
            success(input.value);
        }else{
            cancel();
        }
    }

    //submit new value on blur or change
    input.addEventListener("change", onChange);
    input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);

    //submit new value on enter
    input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 13:
            success(input.value);
            break;

            case 27:
            cancel();
            break;
        }
    });

    return input;
}
```

You can then add this to a column in the column definition:
{title:"Date", field:"date", editor:dateEditor}

Comment: Thank you Oli -very helpful! I'm using GAS as a front end so upon clicking a date, it takes me to a blank screen ....usercodeapppanel#. But what you provided with the OnRendered explanation should get me well on my way. Thanks again - and Tabulator has been fantastic!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, it is great to hear you are enjoying using Tabulator. if this answer helped you out, would you mind marking it as the correct answer to help others find it too. Cheers :)

Comment: Absolutely. I've spent several hours today trying to fix the issue regarding it going to another page. Do you happen to have any ideas by chance?

Comment: I don't need anything to be submitted as I have that handled later on via onEdit. I just need the date that is picked via jquery ui datepicker to show in the tabulator cell.  I can now enter it directly in the cell. The issue I'm having with the above code is when I try to use the datepicker, upon selecting a date it redirects the entire page away.

Comment: Let me perhaps ask my question a different way. Does the code above work for you - with the date ending up in the tabulator cell after it is clicked in the datepicker?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing reply there, i got muddled as to which question i was answering. the issue will be happening because your table is inside a form element, if you move it outside the form element it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get what Oli suggested to work. Then again, I might be missing something simple as I am much more of a novice. After a lot of trial+error, this is the hack kind of approach I ended up creating -- builds upon Oli's onRender suggestion but then uses datepicker's onSelect the rest of the way.

The good: The datepicker comes up regardless where in the cell the user clicks -- so the user is less tempted to try and enter manually. If the user happens to try and enter manually, they can do so.
The less-than-ideal: If the user does manually enter, the datepicker won't go away until he/she clicks elsewhere. But not a showstopper.

```
     //Date Editor//
var dateEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){

var cellValue = cell.getValue(),
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");

    input.style.padding = "4px";
    input.style.width = "100%";
    input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    input.value = typeof cellValue !== "undefined" ? cellValue : "";


    onRendered(function(){
    $(input).datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var dateselected = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var cleandate = (moment(dateselected, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
      $(input).datepicker( "destroy" );
      cell.setValue(cleandate,true);
      cancel();

     },
   });
    input.style.height = "100%"; 

   });


    return input;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use datepicker from [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), this is my code

```
var dateEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
    //create and style input
    var editor = $("<input type='text'/>");
    // datepicker
    editor.datepicker({
        language: 'ja',
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function() {
        if(editorParams != 'row'){
            editor.trigger('keyup');
        }else{
            editor.trigger('change');
        }
    });

    editor.css({
        "padding": "3px",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
    });

    editor.val(cell.getValue());

    onRendered(function(){
        editor.focus();
    });

    editor.on("blur", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(editor.val() === '') {
            success(cell.getValue());
        }
        else {
            //submit new value on change
            editor.on("change", function (e) {
                success(editor.val());
            });

        }
    });

    return editor;
}
```